# Turn URL parameter into SHA1 either in twig or in route or any other place

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How can I generate URL below in Twig? I would accept any other solution, not only twig, as long as the hashId is turned into SHA1 format.

**Note:** `brand.id` is coming from DB as in plain numbers like `1, 2, ,3, 10, 23, 69, .....` and needs to be hashed. I don't want to store hashed data in DB!

**Generating the URLs like this:**

```
{% for brand in brands %}
   <a href="{{ path('product_delete_process', {'hashId':brand.id }) }}">Delete</a>
   <br />
{% endfor %}
```

**OUTCOME URL:**

```
...../product/delete/process/12df54dg54th897yhjrt65DFesrSDE1123ASa
```

**ROUTE:**

```
product_delete_process:
    pattern:  /product/delete/process/{hashId}
    defaults: { _controller: ProDuctBundle:ProductDelete:process }
    methods:  [GET]
    requirements:
        hashId:   "[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create your own custom TWIG filter that would apply encoding to your URL parameter - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

And then use it in your template:

```
{% for brand in brands %}
   <a href="{{ path('product_delete_process', {'hashId':brand.id|sha1_encode }) }}">Delete</a>
   <br />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Aha. This is very nice thing! I never heard about this before and seems to be the most exciting option cos I'll learn something else while trying to find a solution. Thanks, it is very helpful.